# Where to search for Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, nuget

Hi does any of you know where can I find **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client** using nuget? I can't find it because I'm trying to create instance of **TfsConfigurationServer**.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These assemblies are shipped with visual studio for vs2013 located under the extensions tab.

[image]

see the following for an example of how to use the .dll's in a console application
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx

Answer (score 6):

The namespace "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client" is in the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll.